# Maven release plugin | Best practice | It is better to modify the version in the POM directly or modify the release.properties file

Tags: java, maven

I have a question about best practices and would appreciate the advice of experts
I've been working with maven-release-plugin for several years, and I have a doubt that what is better to release a new version. Normally I modify the **release.properties** file with the new version to be released and the next one in snapshot, for example:

```
project.rel.com.blabla.generic-module\:my-module=1.1.0
project.dev.com.blabla.generic-module\:my-module=2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After commit this file modified, i make `mvn release:prepare release:perform` from build server, and then, version 1.1.0 is released and 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is generated.

My question is if it is better to modify each pom.xml of the project with the version that I want to release or the mechanism that I use is valid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not modify the `release.properties` manually.

If you just use `mvn release:prepare release:perform --batch-mode` the version is automatically incremented for example from `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0.0` and the next development version will be `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

If you like to change the version to be used for release you can simply do that via:

```
mvn -DreleaseVersion=2.0.0 release:prepare release:perform --batch-mode
```

If you like to define the release version and next developmentVersion you can do that via:

```
mvn -DreleaseVersion=2.0.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.1.0-SNAPSHOT release:prepare release:perform --batch-mode
```

If you have a multi module build you should configure to use `autoVersionSubmodules=true` which usually is defined in your pom and not manually from command line.

- https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html
- https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Based on what you told me I will make the necessary changes to the server.
Thank you very much again!